# What's the natural way to ask about the current degrees of the weather?

Tags: phrase-request

What's the natural way to ask about degrees of the weather?

Can I ask: "What's the temperature?" or "What's the weather like now?" and people will understand I'm asking the degrees?

Asking "How many degrees of Celsius are now?" or "How many degrees are now?" are natural? Or maybe another way to ask appropriately what I want.

Comment: I would say, "what's the temperature?", but it's almost impossible that someone in the US would answer back the temperature in Celsius.

Comment: "How many degrees (of Celsius) are now?" is quite unnatural. Asking "How many?" for temperature doesn't work because you don't count degrees. Temperature is just a number; it's not a number OF anything.

Comment: To ask specifically about the temperature in Celsius (as opposed to Fahrenheit if in the U.S.), you could ask "what is the temperature in degrees Celsius?".

Comment: *What's the weather like now?* would normally be answered with a statement about the current ***wind*** and/or ***precipitation*** (rain, snow,...), rather than temperature. If you specifically wanted to know the temperature, you'd probably explicitly ask about that.

Comment: "How many degrees of Celsius are now?" is ungrammatical. It would be "How many degrees Celsius is it now?", which is grammatical, but unusual compared to the simple "What's the temperature?".

Comment: @HelloGoodbye I'm not sure that the problem is with the countability of degrees, but rather with "are now?". Whilst unusual, I think we can contrive some valid examples e.g. "Alice: the temperature difference is large. Bob: how many degrees Celsius?".

Comment: That's true. I guess you're right.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Weather doesn't have degrees, it has states and conditions.

If you ask what the weather is like, you'll likely get a response similar to the following:

> It's (windy, raining, sunny, snowing, hot, cold).

It would be unusual to get a response with the actual temperature unless it's something particularly noteworthy:

> "You wouldn't believe how hot it is! It's up to 35°C / 95°F!"

---

If the temperature is specifically what you want to know, then you should ask about it specifically:

> "What's the temperature?"

Answer (score 15):

"What's the temperature outside?" would be a totally natural way to ask this. You can shorten this to just "What's the temperature?" if you think it's clear that you're talking about the temperature outside. You can also add "now" or "right now" if you want.

If you know that it's cold outside, it would also sound totally natural to ask "How cold is it outside?"; and likewise, if it's hot, you can ask "How hot is it outside?"

"How many degrees are now?" sounds ungrammatical. On the other hand, the question "How many degrees are there now?" would be grammatical—but it's still incorrect! After all, we don't say "There are 30 degrees outside"; we say "It's 30 degrees outside". So you can't ask about "how many degrees there are".

You could ask "How many degrees is it now?", and that wouldn't be incorrect—but it's just not something people say. If you ask the question that way, people will think that maybe you don't know the word "temperature".

In summary:

- What's the temperature outside? – good
- How cold is it outside? – good if it's cold outside
- How hot is it outside? – good if it's hot outside
- How many degrees are now? – ungrammatical
- How many degrees are there now? – incorrect (but not ungrammatical)
- How many degrees is it now? – sounds strange (but not incorrect)

Comment: Also, depending where you are, you'd probably need to confirm whether you're asking about degrees Celsius or Fahrenheit.  (For example, the UK has been using Celsius for many decades, but some older folk still think in Fahrenheit.  While in the USA, I think Fahrenheit is still customary.)

Comment: @gidds: In the US, you will be given Fahrenheit. Celsius basically doesn't exist here.

Comment: "How many degrees is it outside?" is fine, it's just used less because it puts emphasis on "degrees", the unit of measurement, whereas using the word "temperature" is more neutral. There are times where you want this emphasis, for example "What's the temperature outside?" "Cold." "How many degrees?" "Forty or so."

Answer (score 3):

Asking "what's the temperature?" or "what's the temperature outside? are both perfectly normal. However, your response will almost certainly be in Fahrenheit if you are in the U.S. If you are in the U.S. and you need to ask specifically for the temperature in Celsius, the best way would be to ask, "what's the temperature in Celsius?"

This would be a shortened and casual way of asking "what is the current local temperature measured in Celsius?" However, it can be assumed in casual conversation that you are asking for the temperate here and now and that Celsius is a unit of measurement.

Therefore, you can simply ask: "what's the temperature in Celsius?"

Comment: I'd just add that "what's the temperature in Celsius?" is grammatical, but an unusual question to ask in the US. It implies that the person you're asking not only knows the exact current temperature (unless they have a phone or smartwatch where this information is readily available, that's not a figure that many people know all the time), but also can quickly convert it into Celsius, which is not commonly used. It would be a bit like asking someone the current barometric pressure: a proper question in the English language, but not one most people can answer for you without research.

Comment: @ZachLipton Presumably, if you did ask someone if the US the current barometric pressure, the answer would be in some crazy units like "inches of mercury" that nobody else in the world understands anyway :) (My favourite "international units in the US " anecdote is Boeing's version of metric units for designing their planes. The fuselage is made in section 2.54 meters long. That is exactly 8 feet 4 inches, of course. "A hundred inches" is as close to "metric units" as you are going to get!

Comment: @ZachLipton The U.S. is a large country with numerous different social norms. I'm sure your comment would be correct if one was to travel to an area of the country that has seem smaller amounts of immigration over the last few years and I can only speak for Northern California, Florida, and Kansas City (the three areas I have personally lived for over a couple years) but many people in all of those locations commonly speak in terms of Celsius (although not so much in Kansas City) due to the large Latin populations that have been immigrating there.

Comment: Rare that you would ask "What's the temperature in Celsius?" unless you were in a "professional" context. You'd say: "What's the temperature (outside, or whatever)?" And you'd get the answer something like "About 25, I think," and the Celsius or Fahrenheit nature would be understood in the context it is given. "Is that Celsius or Fahrenheit?" may then be asked in an ironic tone if the weather is distinctly unusual. And in any case, in colloquial contexts, the word "Centigrade" would often (erroneously, yes I know) be used.

Comment: @PrimeMover What's wrong with saying "centigrade"? If anything it's more accurate than "Celsius" given that the scale Anders Celsius proposed was the other way up.

Answer (score 2):

Cambridge Dictionary defines [temperature](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/temperature) as:

> the measured amount of heat in a place or in the body.

When you are asking about the temperature outside, it simply means that you are asking for the degree of the heat outside.

Whereas Cambridge Dictionary defines [weather](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weather) as:

> the conditions in the air above the earth such as wind, rain, or temperature, especially at a particular time over a particular area.

When someone asks for the weather outside, that person is generally asking if it’s hazy, windy or rainy. Weather is a broader term which includes **temperature** and other units such as humidity, precipitation, cloudiness and visibility.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, temperature doesn't need to be measured in degrees, Kelvin are also a valid measurement, although an unlikely response :)

Comment: @larkey the Kelvin is majorly used for scientific purposes and we never use it for measuring temperature of the environment.

Comment: @larkey: Kelvin also uses degrees.  In fact, the same degrees as centigrade (or Celsius, if you're European).  The scales just use different starting points: 0 C is (IIRC) 273 and a bit K.

Comment: @jamesqf I am afraid I have to tell you that the kelvin is not written as a degree. The kelvin scale never uses a degree as its SI unit.

Comment: @jamesqf Nope, its 0 K but -273°C. Just like 180° and π rad for the circumference.

Comment: @Princesadh -- agreed, but while it's not written °K, it is still often voiced as "degrees Kelvin". But then it's also common to just say "250 Kelvin" or whatever.

Comment: @PrimeMover it’s informal to say “degrees kelvin”.

Comment: @Princesadh Exactly my point. It's informal but not technically "incorrect". A "degree Kelvin" is a "degree", in that a "degree" is an increment on a scale of whatever measurable quantity. For that matter, a metre is a "degree" of distance, but it is not usually called that.

Comment: @Princesadh: Sorry, but it IS often written as "°K" or "N degrees K".  You perhaps may argue that that's incorrect according to some authority or other, but the English language really isn't subject to any prescriptive authority.

Comment: @jamesqf I am interested to know that why you consider degrees kelvin to be correct. As discussed earlier, it’s informal to say ‘degrees kelvin’. Something which is informal isn’t said to be official. Just because it’s convenient to understand “degrees kelvin” that doesn’t make it correct to use it. I would have got my marks deducted, if I had used “degrees kelvin” in my science exam.

Comment: @jamesqf Those who use Kelvin at all, will do so in a scientific context. There, scientific correctness will be what counts, not poetic licence :)

Comment: @Princesadh: Did I not write clearly enough?   First, it is common usage, and English is descriptive, not prescriptive. If you need to go beyond that, it uses the same units as °C, just a different origin, therefore it would be illogical to call one degrees and the other not.  IDK where you went to school, but I'm glad my instructors were not concerned with such things.  And while I don't recall any of my papers referring to absolute temperatures, if I had occasion to, I would probably use °K.

Comment: @jamesqf “IDK where you went to school” please maintain peace.

Comment: @jamesqf please visit this link: https://www.physlink.com/education/askexperts/ae369.cfm. You seem really confused.

Comment: @jamesqf No, it's not illogical, actually it's illogical to say °K, just like it's illogical to say "this angle is π degree radian". It's also not just "language" that develops but it's a scientific unit. Even if people started saying "degree metres" it would be *wrong*. And as asserted, K are mostly used in science, and as someone from science: No we *do* say K, not °K. I can't remember when I heard someone say °K. It's far more common to (also wrongly) say 5C instead of 5°C, but we don't wanna talk electric charge here.